# Deleting an embedded string in a text file with grep or anything else via terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, grep, ls

I have a text file and would like to remove '/d0/' '/d1/' ... '/d5/' from the each line of text.  I know I can ls the files with '/d*/'.  I figure it is `grep -vE '//d*// filename > filename`  Alternatively I could create the text file of filenames from the remote server via `ls` but it adds the extension onto the file name in the text file.  Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of actual input data and your desired output: as it stands it's hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do

```
anycommand filename > filename
```

The shell processes the redirection before launching the command. The `> file` redirection will first truncate the file so its size is 0 bytes. Then, when the command starts, it has an empty file to work with.

The [`sponge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sponge.1.html) command from the `moreutils` package exists for just this purpose:

```
anycommand filename | sponge filename
```

---

To answer your question, you'll want to use `sed` to edit your file

```
sed -i 's,/d[0-5]/,,' filename
```

sed's `-i` flag will save the changes back to the same filename.

Comment: This is a good ans